# How to specify location of TOC when exporting to LATEX

Tags: latex

I would like my TOC to be positioned after the affiliations of authors.
However, TOC by default is positioned right after author names.
Is there a way to specify this?

Comment: By default, the TOC is is placed after the title page (which includes authors' affiliations). Not clear why you are getting something different. Check the produced `.tex` file and see if something looks fishy.

Comment: Any news on this?

Comment: No, i couldn't find any strange setting that is preventing this.